# Ruby grep binary files?

Tags: ruby, grep, binary-data, binutils

I have been using this so far

```
system 'strings binary-file.dmp | grep search_string'
```

Is there something more "Ruby like"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my quick-and-dirty strings.rb:

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

ARGV.each do |filename|
    File.open filename,"rb" do |f|
        f.each_line do |line|
            line.scan(/([\x32-\x7e]{4,})/).each {|a| puts a[0]}
        end
    end
end
```

This is not a work of art or anything - it only works in straight US-ASCII.  The regex bascially means "all groups of printable US-ASCII characters of size 4 charaters or more".  This is essentially what `strings(1)` does.